# What is happening with resharper in vs2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, resharper

[image]

the original code is like this.

```
                         else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case UserType.Individual:
                    {
```

Comment: -1: this would be better as a bug report directly to JetBrains, not a question here.

Comment: i believe this is not a bug, why down vote? that is why I am asking here because I believe this is not a bug. :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to install SP1 for Visual Studio. See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1204

Comment: Is this a "known issue" thing (from your intimate knowledge of resharper), or a side note? (just askin')

Comment: Can you let us know how it goes - I see the same thing

Comment: sure will do, I left the computer at the office will be back tomorrow.

Comment: @Marc, frequent support call, I believe it is on the FAQ list also. Will check tomorrow, if not - will add :)